# Hierarchical XamDataGrid XamComboEditor Binding / DataContext Ancestor

Tags: wpf, xamdatagrid

I think this should be easy but I'm having trouble binding the itemssource values on a combox column that is part of a hierarchical XamDataGrid.  My datacontext is set on the GRID containing the Data Grid, to a collection.

The hiererchy high-level looks like this:

Table (root)
  --> Field (Combobox collection defined here)
     --> Mappings (Combobox column here)

Each field can have its own mapping, and the Target Values on the mappings are unique to each Field.

In code behind, I build up my collection and set the DataContext to the Grid:
DataGridTransformations.DataContext = MapColl;

Here's a screen that helps me make more sense:

[image: Example of issue]

Here's the XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridTransformations" Background="#FFFAFADB" DataContext="MSC_Conversion_Tools.Models.MapSourceColl">
                <Custom:XamDataGrid x:Name="DataGridTransformations" DataSource="{Binding TableEntities}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" Width="966" Loaded="DataGridTransformations_Loaded">
                    <Custom:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                        <Custom:FieldLayout>
                            <Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <Custom:Field Name="TableEntities"/>
                            </Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        </Custom:FieldLayout>

                        <Custom:FieldLayout Key="TableEntities">
                            <Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <Custom:Field Name="EntityName" Label="Table Name"></Custom:Field>
                                <Custom:Field Name="Fields"/>
                            </Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>



                        </Custom:FieldLayout>

                        <Custom:FieldLayout Key="Fields">
                            <Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <Custom:Field Name="FieldName" Label="Field"></Custom:Field>
                                <Custom:Field Name="DefaultValue" Label="Default Value"></Custom:Field>
                                <Custom:Field Name="DefaultOnlyNonNullValues" Label="Default: Include Null Fields?" Width="300"></Custom:Field>
                                <Custom:Field Name="FunctionWrapName" Label="Function"></Custom:Field>
                                <Custom:Field Name="Mappings"></Custom:Field>
                            </Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        </Custom:FieldLayout>

                        <Custom:FieldLayout Key="Mappings">
                            <Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                                <Custom:Field Name="SourceValue" Label="Source Vaue"></Custom:Field>
                                <Custom:Field Name="TargetValue" Label="Target Value" >
                                    <Custom:Field.Settings>
                                        <Custom:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}" AllowEdit="True">
                                            <Custom:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
                                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MappingTargetCmbValues, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Custom:XamDataGrid}}}" />
                                                    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="ValuePath" Value="Id" />
                                                </Style>
                                            </Custom:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>

                                        </Custom:FieldSettings>
                                    </Custom:Field.Settings>
                                </Custom:Field>

                            </Custom:FieldLayout.Fields>
                        </Custom:FieldLayout>


                    </Custom:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
                </Custom:XamDataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

Also here is my Field class which contains my combobox values collection, MappingTargetCmbValues(I'm probably not doing this right either):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MSC_Conversion_Tools.Models
{
    class Field
    {
        public Field(string Name)
        {
            FieldName = Name;
            DefaultOnlyNonNullValues = false;
        }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
        public Boolean DefaultOnlyNonNullValues { get; set; }
        public string FunctionWrapName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Mapping> Mappings { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MappingTargetCmbValue> MappingTargetCmbValues;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but it looks like **MappingTargetCmbValues** is a field and not a property. Btw binding to Host.DataContext.MappingTargetCmbValues with a RelativeSource of Self would probably be better than a FindAncestor binding.

Comment: Thanks yes I had to make that field a property and changed the XAML to this: 
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ParentDataRecord.DataItem.MappingTargetCmbValues}" />